# layout dijits within dojo custom widgets

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've got a number of tools to build that are accessed by clicking a dijit/Tree on the main htm page.  My plan was to make each of the tools a custom widget.  The problem I'm having is that some of these tools have some pretty long forms that would require accordions/and or tab containers.  Since _WidgetsInTemplateMixin doesnt support layout widgets as children I'm trying to find some way to work around.  I would like to keep using dojo because its built into some of the functionality of the tools(esri maps).  Can accordions and tab containers be achieved using some existing css library?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a bunch of examples of making an accordion using css that look like they will work really well.  some good ones:

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-content-accordion/

http://andornagy.com/pure-css-accordion/